# AS3 Multiple elements in array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Is there a way to Create an array that is 20 in .length that randomize (and multiply if needed) another array that is 5 in .length?

Sorry if there are too little information, I'm pretty new to AS3.

I'm trying to create a reaction game where the arrow keys to press will come at random

```
ArrowArray: Array = new array(5) //This array contains 5 elements 
ArrowArray[arrowup, arrowdown, arrowleft, arrowright];
```

So I now need to, using the ArrowArray to generate the level where 20 arrow keys will be generated on screen for the player to press.

Comment: What do you mean by multiply? And yes, there is always a way :P

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Yes, you can declare an Array with length 20: `var a:Array = new Array(20)` or `var a:Array = []; a.length = 20;` or `var a:Array = []; a[20] = 'some value';` You might try and clarify the rest of your question by describing what it is you're trying to do (and perhaps why).

Comment: I gave you the absolutely correct answer to this yesterday, in spite of your incoherent way of asking a question.  Why, instead of acknowledging, are you re-posting and, frankly, wasting people's time?

Comment: Sorry that I wasted your time Craig, I appreciate that you spent your time to answer my poorly phrased question. I'm fairly new here so I wasn't sure if anyone was going to reply if I added anything to that post, so sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you meant, but here's a way to create a random array from elements of other array:

```
private function createRandomizedArray( originalArray:Array, newLength:int):Array
{
        var newArray = [];

        for (var i:int = 0; i < newLength; i++)
        {
            var randomElementsIndex:int = originalArray.length * Math.random();
            newArray[i] = originalArray[randomElementsIndex];
        }

        return newArray;
}
```

When I tested this with this code:

```
var a:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
trace(createRandomizedArray(a, 20));
```

The output was:

```
3,2,1,2,2,5,5,4,5,1,2,1,2,2,5,5,3,5,2,2
```

Of course it works not only with integers, you can use this generic function to create all kinds of arrays: string, mixed, classes, objects, anything.

Hope it helps!